# Unity, rotating a Vector3 along an axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

For example, I have a Vector3 and I waant to rotate it relatively Y-axis (Vector3.up). Can I do it using built-in methods, or should I use coordinate geometry and trigonometry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Quaternions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) to rotate vectors.

For example, to rotate a source vector by 30 degrees the way you want, you can use [AngleAxis()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html) :

```
Vector3 v = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-30, Vector3.up) * sourceVect;
```

Comment: Just as a side note I would rephrase `You need to use Quaternions to rotate vectors` to .. you **can** ;) `Quaternion` just already implements the underlying matrix math for you  .. in this case using `Quaternion.Euler(0, 30, 0);` might be easier to read

Comment: As I mentioned to Juris, `Euler()` is more about rotation as referenced to the world axis. The OP needed a relative rotation. Agreed with the rephrasing :)

Comment: quaternion multiplication is always relativ to the original quaternion ;) Both will do exactly the same thing here .. just wanted to mention that Euler might be easier to read as the more generic AngleAxis